How to authenticate blob storage data while running a job script on Azure Machine Learning
I'm not able to access my data in ADLS gen2 blob container when I try to run a python script for data preprocessing in Azure Machine Learning Workspace. I'm working on a ML pipeline but I cant seem to fix this issue.
Here's how I'm initializing my credential and the MLclient:
from azure.ai.ml import command
from azure.ai.ml import Input, Output
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.ai.ml import Input, Output
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import os

# Set up Azure ML client

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
ml_client = MLClient(
credential=credential,
subscription_id="XXX",
resource_group_name="YYY",
workspace_name="ZZZ",
)
data_prep_job = command(
inputs={
"data": Input(type="uri_file", path=data_input_path),
"test_train_ratio": 0.2,
},
outputs={
"train_data": Output(type="uri_folder", path="azureml://datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/output/train_data"),
"test_data": Output(type="uri_folder", path="azureml://datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/output/test_data"),
},
code=data_prep_src_dir,
command="""python data_prep.py \
\--data ${{inputs.data}} --test_train_ratio ${{inputs.test_train_ratio}} \
\--train_data ${{outputs.train_data}} --test_data ${{outputs.test_data}} \
""",
environment="AzureML-sklearn-0.24-ubuntu18.04-py37-cpu:1",
display_name="Data Preparation Job",
compute="my-model-compute"
)

# Submit the job

submitted_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(data_prep_job)
ml_client.jobs.stream(submitted_job.name)

I am getting this error:
Error Code: ScriptExecution.StreamAccess.Authentication Native Error: error in streaming from input data sources    StreamError(PermissionDenied(None)) => permission denied when access stream. Reason: None   PermissionDenied(None) Error Message: Authentication failed when trying to access the stream. Make sure you have correct permissions set up. Err("")| session_id=2fe2ca-a9c7-d0161be


When i try to read the data through the notebook cells in Azure ML through DefaultCredentials(), it's working just fine. However, it's giving me an error when i try to run a python script of the similar code. I have provided Blob Storage Contributor role to the AML compute resource and my workspace. Perhaps, I'm not passing the athentication information correctly?

Is your job cluster have managed identity enabled?

Add the python script you submitting to job and what is the path you are giving as input?

When you are using datastore uri to access data in interactive development like notebook the default credential/identity passthrough is automatically handled by azure ml fsspec, which is called when you to read data using pandas.
Since, you mentioned

I have provided Blob Storage Contributor role to the AML compute resource

Then you need to pass identity to command job like below.
data_prep_job = command(
inputs={
"data": Input(type="uri_file", path=data_input_path),
"test_train_ratio": 0.2,
},
outputs={
"train_data": Output(type="uri_folder", path="azureml://datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/output/train_data"),
"test_data": Output(type="uri_folder", path="azureml://datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/output/test_data"),
},
code=data_prep_src_dir,
command="""python data_prep.py \
\--data ${{inputs.data}} --test_train_ratio ${{inputs.test_train_ratio}} \
\--train_data ${{outputs.train_data}} --test_data ${{outputs.test_data}} \
""",
environment="AzureML-sklearn-0.24-ubuntu18.04-py37-cpu:1",
display_name="Data Preparation Job",
compute="my-model-compute",
identity=ManagedIdentityConfiguration(client_id)
)

Here, i given extra parameter identity which takes the identity configured in your compute resource and make sure you have given necessary roles for storage access.
check this document on accessing data in jobs.
